# Command "python" works in windows power-shell, but not if in a .sh file

Tags: python, windows, bash, powershell

Good afternoon,
I have been stuck with this problem for a couple of days now, and can't seem to get out of it.

Before running a model I have to generate the data in a certain format. To do so I have to run a .sh file, in which there are some calls to python. If I run the command "python" inside the power shell(my machine has Windows 10 as the Operating System), it works just fine. I have infact addedd python to the PATH variable of my system variables.

If instead I try to run the .sh file, in which I have calls to python, I get the following behaviour:

```
PS C:\Users\....\scripts>bash FILE_NAME.sh SRC_FILE.csv
data_mr exist
Start to converting data.
FILE_NAME.sh: line 48: python: command not found
```

It seems that when I try to run python inside a file, he cannot recognize/retrieve it from the system variables, which seems very odd to me. The bash file I am trying to run is provided by https://github.com/mindspore-ai/models/tree/master/official/gnn/bgcf , hence I doubt the problem is in the file.

Do you have any idea of where the problem could be and how to possibly solve it?

Comment: If you run `bash -c 'echo $PATH'`, does it show that the bash Path includes the directory where python is installed?

Comment: Also, depending on your version of bash, line endings can matter. Does your file have Unix-style LF line endings, or Windows-style CRLF?

Comment: To answer your first question: yes it does in include the directory where python is installed. As a side when I run your suggest code I get, prior to the list of paths, the following message: /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Strange that it's on the path like that, but not finding it. Grasping at straws, buy does `bash -c 'which python'` also output what you'd expect?

Comment: But my best guess would be that when you checked out the files from the bgcf repo, you had the Git setting to automatically convert line ends to CRLF (my suggestion: change that!), and you're running a version of bash that doesn't support Windows-style line ends. Please test converting the file to Linux style line ends and let us know if the error persists.

Comment: Running bash -c 'which python' outputs nothing

Comment: Ok I will do as suggested, let you know the outcome when I have it

Comment: If bash -c 'which python' outputs nothing, then that's consistent with bash later telling you "python: command not found". There's probably something wrong with your path, maybe the exact formatting is not what bash needs? Can you share what my echo path command output in the question?

Comment: /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/windows/system32:/mnt/c/windows:/mnt/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Users/lucas/AppData/Local/Programs/Julia 1.5.3/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Novell/iPrint:/mnt/c/Users/lucas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/'

Comment: That error at the beginning of the output is weird. I don't know what to make of it, but it's probably a symptom of something. I'm stumped, but more questions: what Windows shell (cmd? powershell?) are calling this from? where and how is bash installed (wsl? Git bash? something else?). Hopefully someone with a setup more like yours can help.

Comment: Thank you anyhow for the availability. The ends are linux style, so that cannot be the problem. I am running from powershell, and bash is installed trough wsl. I probably have to check if I have some problems in my wsl.

Comment: You obviously did not have your PATH right, but you did not show how you have set up your environment, so it is difficult to advice something.  Since - according to your posting -  you are running a non-interactive non-login bash, setting up the shell can be a bit tricky, because non of the files in the directory which bash believes is your home directory, won't be executed. You also did not specify which bash implementation you are using. First you need to find out which is your home directory for bash, and then you can set the variable `BASH_ENV` to specify a file processed by your bash.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows does not have a shell which can handle `.sh` files. I believe you have a so-called WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), which means that you have a Linux/UNIX-system in top of your Windows.
This system has its own environment variables (check `env | grep "PATH"`). I would advise you to find the location of Python and add it to that specific `PATH` variable, but be aware that your Windows Python might not run on that Linux/UNIX system.

Oh, now that I think about it: are you talking about `bash` or `GIT-bash`?

Comment: OP is running `bash FILE_NAME.sh ...` so they're just relying on the bash instance on the PATH that's active on their command prompt, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Using this "#!/usr/bin/env python" for shebang line, (first line for .sh file)
fixed the issue for me